# unknown librarie when modularize code python

Tags: python, pandas

I try to modularize my python code .

In my main code the notebook, I insert this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import my_math
df["std_line_amount_log_normal"] = df["std_line_amount"].apply(lambda f: my_math.feature_log_normalize(f))
```

And I create a module called "my_math" as an external .py file : here the code :

```
def feature_std_normalize(f):
    return (f - mu) / std

def feature_log_normalize(f):
   # return (f - mu) / std
    return np.log(f+1)
```

When I run this statement in my notebook :

```
df["std_line_amount_log_normal"] = df["std_line_amount"].apply(lambda f: my_math.feature_log_normalize(f))
```

I get this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-32256b03bfa2> in <module>()
----> 1 df["std_line_amount_log_normal"] = df["std_line_amount"].apply(lambda f: my_math.feature_log_normalize(f))

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2549             else:
   2550                 values = self.asobject
-> 2551                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2552 
   2553         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-90-32256b03bfa2> in <lambda>(f)
----> 1 df["std_line_amount_log_normal"] = df["std_line_amount"].apply(lambda f: my_math.feature_log_normalize(f))

~/SageMaker/my_math.py in feature_log_normalize(f)
     10 
     11 def feature_log_normalize(f):
---> 12    # return (f - mu) / std
     13     return np.log(f+1)
     14 

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Ca you help me to resolve this problem please?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import numpy also in external .py so:

```
import numpy as np
def feature_std_normalize(f):
    return (f - mu) / std

def feature_log_normalize(f):
   # return (f - mu) / std
    return np.log(f+1)
```

Comment: Just for try - use something which use numpy in your main file. For example init empty array `result = numpy.zeros(shape=(5,2))` or something similar to check if your lib is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you installed NumPy for Python 3, you may have used the installation for Python 2 in your previous code. Hope this helps