# Are some python packages global in nature?

Tags: python, logging, scope, package, rpy2

It seems like some python packages, for example logging and rpy2, once imported, have their scopes available across all modules that import them. Pretty much all the other packages I've worked with appear to only have their scopes local to where they are imported.

I've tried googling / stack overflowing this question, but the common key words make that difficult.

Can someone explain whether there is a difference in how some package scopes behave when imported?

Comment: All modules/packages get created and executed once when they are first imported, and have a single global scope (a dictionary) which is shared. You'll have to specify what you mean by "have their scopes local to where they are imported". Ideally some sample code of the two different kinds of behaviour you're observing and what you expect might have happened differently.

Comment: @AlexHall Maybe he's talking about the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147462/unknown-librarie-when-modularize-code-python

Comment: @AlexHall so for example when I load rpy2 I am essentially creating a SINGLE r environment that I can access from ANY module where I've imported the rpy2 package. The rpy2 R environment seems to persist and keep variable names regardless of which module I import the package from. Same kind of behavior from logging package - once I load it, every place where it is imported accesses the same root information. This behavior is distinct from most all other packages I use where there does not appear to be any shared global values or root info.

Comment: I've stated that all modules have the same behaviour where everything is shared, like you're seeing with logging. You've pretty much just restated your question. Show a sample of things not being shared in other packages.